# On WIX how do I copy a file from an older installation when re-installing

Tags: c#, wix

I have a product which uses WIX to install.
This is my install sequence:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <RemoveExistingProducts Before="InstallInitialize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Which as I understand, deletes the entire older version upon re-installation.
This is the behavior I want to preserve, but I also want to copy a specific file from 
the older version.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want from a deployment of a new MSI will be almost impossible because you cannot execute a custom action before RemoveExistingProducts that requires elevated privileges (This might work if you are not installing in a UAC controlled folder like prgram files - but I have never tried that).

One workaround is to modify the existing MSI by creating a bootstrapper (I have no idea if this works tho!)– see the answer to this question: [How to execute Custom Action before RemoveExistingProducts with After="InstallValidate" in WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501361/how-to-execute-custom-action-before-removeexistingproducts-with-after-installva)

When I have written installers in the past, I have written a custom action that copies the files out to a temporary folder on uninstall (The uninstall for the previous version of the MSI gets called by the new MSI when you upgrade) and then just inspect and clear this folder out when the new MSI installs (The upgrade part). This approach does leave a lot of files hanging around if you just uninstall (not upgrade) but as I am only interested in configuration files – this actually works out quite well as if a customer returns I won't have lost all their configuration.

This of course does not fix your immediate problem as this will only start working after a version which backs up relevant files on uninstall is distributed – but it has worked well for me for the last 3 years.

HTH

Comment: If I could know what the previous installation folder was, I think I could do this with the Source Attribute within the file tag